# .equals() equivalent

Tags: objective-c

In java there is a .equals() method.  What is the equivalent in Objective-C since I don't want to use ==?

For example, if I want to compare two arrays, I would go through them and see if their objects match.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.count; i++) {
    if (array1[i].equals(array2[i])) {
      do something
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The strict answer to your question is "use `-isEqual:`".

```
if ([array1[i] isEqual:array2[i]]) { ...
```

That said, if you're trying to figure out if two arrays are equal, you're doing it the wrong way. Instead of a pairwise-comparison on all their elements, just ask if the arrays are equal:

```
if ([array1 isEqual:array2]) { ...
```

Some classes, such as `NSArray*`, also provide specialized equality methods that restrict the type of the compared object. They're mostly just used to add additional semantic meaning to your code. If you want to use it, it would look like

```
if ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]) { ...
```

If you use this style, just remember that the compared object must indeed be the correct class.